# Feature selection caused more overfitting

Tags: machine-learning

What does it mean if I used *sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel* to select features and *cross-validation score* went up but the *testset score* went down. This was even more significant compared to when I did not use feature selection.

Does this mean it's causing more overfitting?

I thought feature selection is used to reduce overfitting.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Feature selection doesn't always mean reducing overfitting, feature selection is mainly used to reduce dimensionality. When we remove the least important features from the model, we reduce the model’s complexity and some noise in the data. Doing so will help to further mitigate overfitting but it's not always the case.
Feature selection determines where the appropriate decision boundaries should be, and their complexity.
It affects fitting and sampling, and classifier performance, but feature selection cannot always prevent overfitting.